# Can't boot main OS (Ubuntu)

Tags: boot, uefi, bios, boot-repair

A few weeks ago I tried to install Manjaro linux alongside Ubuntu.
I booted it from an USB pendrive, started the installation and mid way it said something along the lines of being unable to mount the disk.
I reboot and now I'm unable to access ubuntu. The computer says there is no disk, to try and reseat it. I start the computer's diagnostic software. It says everything is OK. I run Ubuntu live from another USB and it shows me the Hard Drive and every partition on it.
On the Manjaro forums people everyone said to try and reseat it. I left it as a last resort because logic dictated that there was no problem with the hard disk since I was able to access it. So I reseated it (Disconnect-reconnect) and nothing changed.

Other than that my HDD appears in the BIOS but the usual Ubuntu partition option doesn't appear in the UEFI/BIOS Boot section.
I ran Boot Repair in the Ubuntu live I'm using and it said 
*"GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again."*

I'm not an expert in computers so and all I can guess is there's an issue with either the boot partition or the EFI software (partition?).

Something similar had happened to this same computer in 2016 and I fixed it by switching from legacy mode to UEFI in the BIOS configuration. This doesn't work now. I've tried every configuration.
My main issue is if the BIOS needs fixing as it seems it's a piece of software deeply ingrained into the hardware itself and I don't want to makes things worse by trying to fix them.

The computer is a Dell Inspiron 14 3000 series with an i3 Intel processor, 1TB HDD and 4GB RAM.

Thanks for reading
I apologize if this case has been answered before I couldn't find infor
Any help is welcome

Comment: You cannot switch back & forth with UEFI & legacy. You have one or the other and need to only boot in that mode. If system is UEFI and you got the missing bios_grub error with Boot-Repair, you booted in BIOS mode and it is trying to fix a BIOS install. But that is not what you want. Re-boot live installer in UEFI mode and rerun Boot-Repair. Post link to summary report.

Comment: Done, changed everything from BIOS to UEFI, disabled Legacy mode and ran BootRepair in Ubuntu Live USB
This is the link I got
http://paste.ubuntu.com/26438239/

Comment: Your sda1 is showing as swap in report, but partition table also shows it flagged as ESP - efi system partition. The ESP must be FAT32 with boot flag. Since boot files were in it, see if you can change format, but not totally reformat  which erases all your boot files. If not you should then be able to totally uninstall/reinstall grub to recreate Ubuntu's UEFI boot files.

Comment: If I erased everything from the UEFI partition by accident, what could I do then? If my pc's a Dell can I just download the Dell UEFI software and reinstall? I've searched for "restore UEFI" but all I get is instructions on how to change from BIOS to UEFI in the setup.

Comment: You can totally reinstall grub and for Windows run its full set of repairs from a USB repair/recovery drive. Boot-Repair makes it relatively easy to do the full uninstall/reinstall of grub2 in its advanced options. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Advanced options screens: 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: My question is: If I deleted everything from sda1 the UEFI partition, would this erase the Dell UEFI software?

Comment: No, but always best to backup. The boot entries can be recreated with your Windows repair/recovery flash drive for Windows and Ubuntu live installer for Ubuntu/grub boot entries.